# How to change background color of selected code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, highlight

By default the background color of selected code is indistinguishable from same token highlighting. E.g. select the token $fileCount and it will be highlighted in (almost) the same color as other occurrences of the same token. This is really nasty.
How do I change the background color of any selected text to be Orange at all times?